# Android ant not working on windows

Tags: android, windows, ant, jar

I have already gone through few threads on this and doing exactly what is mentioned by looking at the accepted answers.

I am using Ant to build my Android project binaries. On the Linux system it works fine and generates binary as expected but on Windows it shows errors.

I am using one lib jar which I have added in `libs` folder. In Windows, while Ant is executing it shows import errors for those classes which are in jar file.

The Ant setup which works fine in Linux system should work as it is except changing few local paths in properties file which I done and have verified many times.

What could be wrong/missing in my setup on Windows?

Comment: I am to facing this issue on windows 7. Any solution on it..?